# How to get the data from below sql table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My Table structure is

```
Value  0   1   2
  X    c   a   d
  Y    d   b   e
  Z    e   c   f
```

my sql query is

```
Declare @CharValue Char(1)='c';
Declare @CharIndex int=0;
Select [Column] from Data_Masking where '['+Cast(@CharIndex as varchar(5))+']'= 'c'
```

I need output as 'X' from my above query but its returns empty.

Comment: in my table all columns datatype is nvarchar(5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't replace a column's name, which needs to be a literal, with a variable. You could do this with dynamic SQL, but unless you really know how to use it, I don't recommend you go down that route.

Considering the simplicity of your table, I suggest a "few" `OR` clauses:

```sql
SELECT [Value]
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE (@@CharIndex = 0 AND [0] = @CharValue)
   OR (@@CharIndex = 1 AND [1] = @CharValue)
   OR (@@CharIndex = 2 AND [2] = @CharValue)
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

I really, as well, recommend better names that `0`, `1` and `2`. Don't use object names that require delimit identification.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bd3cd157c6728f15f79415aed00a6851)

If you "must" do this with dynamic SQL, you would need to do the following. Note, however, that using dynamic SQL comes with a lot of considerations. If you do not understand the security implications of dynamic SQL, you should **not** be using this. In truth, I would suggest you should be changing your design:

```sql
DECLARE @CharValue char(1) = 'c',
        @CharIndex sysname = N'0';

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT [Value] AS [ColumnValue] FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@CharIndex) + N' = @CharValue;';
--PRINT @SQL;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@CharValue char(1)', @CharValue;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=642198ea4dfc49c63b3d60e8c508ff22)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the valuable response, i need to pass the column name 0 as variable like this


Declare @CharIndex int=0;
Select [Column] from Data_Masking where '['+Cast(@CharIndex as varchar(5))+']'= 'c'

Comment: That's what the `OR`'s are for, @RajasekarBaskar ... Note  `@CharColumn = 0 AND [0]...` That'll return the value `'X'` for your sample data, if the value of `@CharColumn` is `0` and `@CharValue` the value `N'c'`.

Comment: I strongly recommend against that answer, @astentx , it's wide open to injection.

Comment: I've added a db fiddle to the answer, to demonstrate it working for you, @RajasekarBaskar .

Comment: @Larnu is that possible to set the EXEC query value in a variable ?

Comment: @Larnu Agree, so I've deleted my comment not to give bad advices. Thank you.

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, @RajasekarBaskar *"You could do this with dynamic SQL, but unless you really know how to use it, I don't recommend you go down that route."* With respect, if you were versed with dynamic SQL you wouldn't be asking this question, thus I intentionally didn't give the answer as a dynamic solution. With 3 columns as well, there's really no need. Dynamic SQL can do this, however, unless you understand the considerations it's dangerous; SQL injection is still a huge problem and poorly written dynamic SQL is a big contributor.

Comment: @Larnu  still same is that possible pass a variable as column in query like above ?

Comment: It is possible, with dynamic SQL, as I state in the answer, @RajasekarBaskar ...

Comment: @Larnu what you given in db riddle that is not possible for me i have huge data in my table can't add all in my query.
is that any other way to solve this issue ?

Comment: @Larnu is that possible to Insert values to Temp table in functions ?

Comment: I've updated the answer, but heed my warnings, @RajasekarBaskar . It's time to fix your design.

Comment: `UNION ALL` 3 queries is another option